# Finding all possible permutations with a sum constraint and a redundancy option? (MATLAB)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, constraints, permutation

I had the following problem in mind:

There is a hypothetical revered musician who is retired. The musician receives royalty checks for their past recordings from time to time. The musician's royalty checks always come in as:

$1, $5, $8, $12, $17, $20, $42, $100, or $200

This means that the musician ONLY receives royalty checks in the amounts specified above. I was wondering, how would I go about computing the total number of possible ways the musician can get paid to amass $1,000? There are some constraints/allowed assumptions in this problem. These are:

(1) There is no cap on the total amount of "checks" the musician can receive to get $1,000. For example, the musician can receive 1,000 $1 checks, 5 $200 checks, or 10 $20 checks and 4 $200 checks, etc. etc.

(2) As (1) implies, you can receive multiples of any checks (in fact, the sum of all singular check options totals $405, making this condition imperative to amass $1,000).

(3) Order matters. Getting paid $200, $200, $100, $100, $100, $100, $100, and $100 is a different "solution" than $100, $100, $100, $100, $100, $100, $200, and $200, which is also a different "solution" than $200, $100, $100, $200, $100, $100, $100, and $100, even though both solutions contain 6 $100 checks and 2 $200  checks. Remember, the musician gets paid checks "from time to time", so the order of check reception makes for the possibility of different solutions (permutations).

I am interested in finding only the total amount of solutions to solve this problem with the given check possibilities, not printing them out.

This is my approach so far:

- Define variables that represent the check possibilities (ex. x1 = 1, x2=5, x3 = 8, etc. etc.)
- Incorporate some if-then statement that checks to see if a set of multiples of x1, x2, x3...xn equals 1000
- If it does, add 1 to some counter variable
- Once all iterations are exhausted/any loops bounds are finished, display the counter value.

However, I don't know how to incorporate x1, x2, x3 and their permutations in a given equation, and I don't know how to solve such equation.

Comment: Is there always a 1$ check? Are all other checks an integer multiple of the smallest check?

Comment: No, there isn't always a $1 check. Having a $1 check all the time would reduce a lot of possibilities that are integer multiples of the "target sum", like 5 $200 bills, or 125 $8 bills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my idea to solve it, following the pattern of dynamic programming:

```
checks=[1,5,8,12,17,20,42,100,200];
target=300;
M=[checks;ones(size(checks))];
while M(1,1)<target
    %we know that there are #possibilities to get a sum of value
    value=M(1,1);
    possibilities=M(2,1);
    M(:,1)=[];
    disp(value)
    %combine value with each check:
    for idx=1:numel(checks)
        if value+checks(idx)<=target
            ii=find(M(1,:)==value+checks(idx),1,'first');
            if isempty(ii)
                M(:,end+1)=[value+checks(idx),possibilities];
            else
                M(2,ii)=M(2,ii)+possibilities;
            end
        end
    end
    %Sort M by value
    [a,idx]=sort(M(1,:));
    M=M(:,idx);
end
```

You can do it manually, create a table (variable M) with the value (summed up) and the number of possibilities to get this value. Initialize it with 1 possibility for each value you can get directly with a check.

Now repeat until you get your intended value:

- Pop your first entry from the table (smallest value). Recombine it with each check (used once) and reinsert it to the table.
- When the combined value is already in the table, sum up the numbers.
- When the combined value is not in the table, insert a new entry.

While on a theoretical level this approac is precises, it quickly exceeds floating point precision. For the target value of 300, the result is ~10^42 which exceeds floating point precision. Is the symbolic toolbox available, then you could switch to vpa?

Comment: `10^42` seems a bit high. If I take the maximum count of each denomination, `{$1:0-300, $5:0-60, $8:0-37, ... $200:0-1}`, and take their product, it only comes to about `10^11`. For a target of `1000` I get `~10^16`. This is certainly in the range of a 64-bit type and not all of the combinations in that count are valid.

Comment: @beker: the order matters, that further increases the possibilities.

Comment: I completely missed that. That should explain a few things.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was easy to follow.

Comment: Is there a mathematical representation for the capped permutation?